# Invalid references created by pgr_createTopology

Tags: pgrouting

I am trying pgr_createTopology on a simple network and it is leaving invalid node references in the `source` and `target` columns. Apparently the segments table is not being updated with the new identifiers created in the `_vertices_pgr` table.

An example:

```
# \d esch.roads
               Table "esch.roads"
 Column |           Type            | Modifiers 
--------+---------------------------+-----------
 id     | numeric(10,0)             | not null
 source | smallint                  | 
 target | smallint                  | 
 geom   | geometry(MultiLineString) | 
Indexes:
    "roads_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

# SELECT pgr_createTopology('esch.roads', 0.0001, 'geom', 'id', 'source', 'target', 'true');
NOTICE:  PROCESSING:
NOTICE:  pgr_createTopology('esch.roads',0.0001,'geom','id','source','target','true')
NOTICE:  Performing checks, pelase wait .....
NOTICE:  Creating Topology, Please wait...
NOTICE:  -------------> TOPOLOGY CREATED FOR  8 edges
NOTICE:  Rows with NULL geometry or NULL id: 0
NOTICE:  Vertices table for table esch.roads is: esch.roads_vertices_pgr
NOTICE:  ----------------------------------------------
 pgr_createtopology 
--------------------
 OK
(1 row)

# SELECT id FROM esch.roads_vertices_pgr WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT source FROM esch.roads);
 id 
----
  2
(1 row)

# SELECT id FROM esch.roads_vertices_pgr WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT target FROM esch.roads);
 id 
----
  6
(1 row)
```

This seems wrong to me, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check your data types? Better to use `integer` data type and not multi-geometries.

```
  Column  |           Type            | Modifiers
----------+---------------------------+-----------
 id       | integer                   |
 source   | integer                   |
 target   | integer                   |
 the_geom | geometry(LineString,4326) |
```

`id` can be also `bigint`.

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I imagine this was caused by the `MULTILINESTRING` type; this perhaps should be in the documentation, and pgr_createTopology should also be issuing an error message.

Comment: I actually thought that pgRouting will only take the first Linestring of a Multilinestring as they rarely exist and are only caused by the default geometry type during import of SHP files for example. I need to check why this didn't work in your case. But in general Multilinestrings don't make sense, if you want to retrieve source and target information.